# Tkinter: Placing widgets on top of other Widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to place an Entry widget on top of a frame but i'm having some trouble with it
(I'm using customtk but i suppose there's no big difference)

```
import customtkinter

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry(500x380)

random_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app, width=480, height=50)
Box1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=app, width=30, height=30)

random_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Box1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

I am expecting the Box1 widget to be on top of the random_frame widget, however in the gui i can't see the Box1. I'm unsure if it's under the frame, but that's what i think is happening.
I tried using the lift() method but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: First of all `app.geometry(500x380)` should be `app.geometry("500x380")` instead. The window is not wide enough to show the entry.  If you comment `app.geometry("500x380")`, you will see the entry.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the frames name in the master of box1
hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).